# Need some help on a password checker program

Tags: java

This is what I have so far

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
  String password;
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
  password = kb.nextLine();
    if (passwordOK(password)) 
    {  
        System.out.println("Valid Password");  
    } 
    else 
    {  
        System.out.println("Invalid Password");  
    }  
}  
   public static boolean passwordOK(String password) {  
  if (password == null) return false;
if (password.length() <= 8) return false;
boolean containsUpperCase = false;
boolean containsLowerCase = false;
boolean containsDigit = false;
for(char ch: password.toCharArray()){
    if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)) containsUpperCase = true;
    if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)) containsLowerCase = true;
    if(Character.isDigit(ch)) containsDigit = true;
}
return containsUpperCase && containsLowerCase && containsDigit;
}
}
```

What I need it to have

• The password must be at least 8 characters long.

• The password must contain at least:

- one alpha character [a-zA-Z];
- one numeric character [0-9];
- one character that is not alpha or numeric, such as

  ! @ $ % ^ & * ( ) - _ = + [ ] ; : ' " , < . > / ?

• The password must not:

- contain spaces;
- begin with an exclamation [!] or a question mark [?];

• The password cannot contain repeating character strings of 3 or more identical characters, such as “1111” or “aaa”.

I'm a little stuck right now so was wondering if somebody could lend a helping hand and maybe throw some sample code my way

edit: ashutosh, How would I add this code to your program without receiving an error

```
  String password2;   
  System.out.print("\nPlease type your password again to confirm: ");
  password2 = kb.nextLine();

  while( !password2.equals(password) )
  {
     System.out.print("Those passwords do not match. Try again: ");
     password2 = kb.nextLine();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building up on the code that you provided, here is what you can do in the most crude way:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String password;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
        password = kb.nextLine();
        if (passwordOK(password))
        {
            System.out.println("Valid Password");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Password");
        }
    }
    public static boolean passwordOK(String password) {
        if (password == null) return false;
        if (password.length() <= 8) return false;
        boolean containsUpperCase = false;
        boolean containsLowerCase = false;
        boolean containsDigit = false;
        boolean containsSpace = false;
        boolean containsSpecialChar = false;
        boolean containExclamationOrQuestionMark = false;
        if (password.charAt(0) == '!' || password.charAt(0) == '?') containExclamationOrQuestionMark = true;
        int i = 0;
        boolean containsRepeatingChars = false;
        String specialChars = "!@$%^&*()-_=+[];:'\",<.>/?";
        for(char ch: password.toCharArray()){
            if (i>=2)  {
                if ((password.charAt(i) == password.charAt(i-1)) && (password.charAt(i-1) == password.charAt(i-2)))
                    containsRepeatingChars = true;
            }
            if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)) containsUpperCase = true;
            if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)) containsLowerCase = true;
            if(Character.isDigit(ch)) containsDigit = true;
            if(ch == ' ') containsSpace = true;
            if(!containsSpecialChar && specialChars.indexOf(ch) >= 0) containsSpecialChar = true;
            i += 1;
        }
        return containsUpperCase && containsLowerCase && containsDigit && !containsSpace && !containExclamationOrQuestionMark && !containsRepeatingChars && containsSpecialChar;
    }
}
```

Although it would be much cleaner with a bunch of regular expressions.

Comment: Added an edit if you can help me with it on my main post

Comment: Just before you print "Valid Password", you can put your code to confirm password.

Comment: Is something wrong with my code because after I enter the first password, I enter the second one to confirm and the second one says Invalid Password

Comment: You will need to show me your entire code for me to know whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

According to the first two points try something like this:

```
boolean match = password.matches("(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[!@#$%&*()_+=|<>?{}\\[\\]~-]).{8}");
```

Change the special characters to yours (all of them are in the bracket [...] ). Remember to use \ before some of them.

For the whitespaces:

```
boolean isWhitespace = password.matches("^\\s*$");
```

Check the exclamation and question mark:

```
boolean startsWithBadChar = password.matches("(!|?).*");
```